# Facebook Developer requiring both Development Key Hash AND Release Key Hash

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I am in the process of setting up my Android App on Facebook Developer. When I enter my Development Key Hash, Facebook is requiring that I enter both the Development Key Hash and the Release Key Hash before I can move on.

The warning I get says "Please enter at least one Development Key Hash or Release Key Hash" but I already entered a Development Key Hash.

Comment: I actually solved this problem. I was missing the last character in my hash.

Answer (score 0):

open app settings on Facebook developers site and check there. If they are configured correctly, check whether status and review is turned on. For more detailed info check out this link:

https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/19/facebook-integration-in-android/#more-109